# How can I unlock the codeview lock button

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

How can I unlock the codeview lock in Content Builder? [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't unlock it in template-based emails. You instead have to edit the template directly.

Release notes from when my team added this feature can be found here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2018_content_builder.htm&type=5

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? Adding a citation or a bit more detail would strengthen the quality of this answer.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your answer with any clarifications. That is not what comments are for. It would be best if you also include any relevant content here.